# UIModalPresentationFormSheet with transparent background?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit

Essentially here I want the modal form sheet to be transparent so I can see the UIView behind it (it's fullscreen).

Is this possible? Setting the `UIView` to not opaque and a `backgroundColor` of `[UIColor clearColor]` doesn't work.

I've noticed when I switch from `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` to another presentation style my view's background is indeed transparent.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is no longer possible. It used to be but Apple has disabled this functionality.

What I've done instead is to just create my `UIView`s like normal and add them as subviews to my main view. I have to dismiss my form sheet and then do this presentation.

Comment: @bneely nope sorry, I'm not sure when this was introduced.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
[modalView.superview setBackgroundcolor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

It'll still dim the background view transparently, but won't cover it with solid gray.

...............................................

### UPDATE FOR iOS 8

My previous solution no longer works for iOS 8. 
There are a lot of steps to get something like this to work for iOS 8. So I've created a nice reusable solution: ModalController
https://github.com/koreyhinton/ModalController.

It's real easy to use and auto-dismisses itself.

```
let modal = ModalController()
modal.content = myCustomView
presentViewController(modal, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you are interested in implementation details, this is how I did it:

Make your modal view controller take up the whole screen and the main view's background will be toggled between clear and semi-dark. You will then have a content view that will be the modal which will be centered with a solid background color. I also use presentation style: `.OverCurrentContext` which I assign in the init method.

```
var content = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    content.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:300, height:300)
    content.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    view.addSubview(content)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.7)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    content!.center = view.center
}
```